# Drupal: rebuild permissions failed, site not accessible

Tags: drupal-7

i have run rebuild permissions on a Drupal site. (Drupal 7.59)

However it failed for some reason, now the site is completely inaccessible, it is saying "No front page content has been created yet."

The admin interface is also not accessible with error "Access denied, you don´t have permissions to access this content."

Any ideas how to override this?  I have complete access though ftp to the server.

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
- gone manually to SQL database, changed the local admin login
- logged in to site.xxx/?q=user  with the just changed local credentials
- restored site with the rebuild permissions command, /admin/reports/status/rebuild